# Importing OpenCV in Python crashes Python

Tags: python, opencv, osx-yosemite

I've been trying to get OpenCV on OS X Yosemite 10.10.2 and start writing some python code, but I'm getting stuck on a fairly frustrating issue.  When I import opencv, python crashes.

```
Python 2.7.3 (v2.7.3:70274d53c1dd, Apr  9 2012, 20:52:43) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cv
Segmentation fault: 11
```

It's followed by a window saying that Python quit unexpectedly[image]

I have tried installing OpenCV through brew, compiling from source, always getting the same problem.  Any idea?

Comment: Take a look at this link: https://medium.com/@manuganji/installation-of-opencv-numpy-scipy-inside-a-virtualenv-bf4d82220313
You may be having internal issues so try installing your modules inside of a virtualenv

Comment: hmmm - apparently even creating a virtualenv is resulting in permission issues - looks like I've got something a little nuts going on with my permissions.  I'll fix that all up and try again.

Comment: permissions + virtualenv suggestion did the trick, thanks!